# How to use material icon in angular 2?

Tags: angular2-template

I am trying to use below code. But home icon is not getting displayed.

```
       <button md-button routerLink="/">
            <md-icon>home</md-icon> 
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add the angular material icon link in index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```